# Why doesn't this call to getQuery work? And what's the fix?

Tags: jquery, query-string

/search.aspx?Search=test

```
function getQuery(name) {
    var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)').exec(window.location.search);
    return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
};


if (getQuery('SearchType') == '') {
   $("#txtSearch").val(getQuery('Search'));
};
```

if I leave out the if statement and just set the value of the textbox it works fine, so I obviously know my getQuery function is working.  It's obviously something to do with the fact that SearchType is NOT '', it's not anything.  I tried "if (getQuery('SearchType')) but that didn't work either.

Must be a simple answer... there always is to my questions :)

Comment: Don't think a link to localhost is going to help us debug.

Comment: That was so you could see the querystring...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you're comparing to an empty string, but `getQuery` is returning null. Change your comparison to this:

```
if (getQuery('SearchType') == null) {
   $("#txtSearch").val(getQuery('Search'));
};
```

Comment: Works.  I swore I tried this.  Must have done a single = or something.  Thanks!